# Accessing Documents Folder on Apple watch through GUI

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-3, nshomedirectory

According to the [App Programming Guide for watchOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html)  it is possible to store data in a Documents folder in the watch app. My code also seems to be doing this sucessfull, as there are no errors.

However, to really debug this, i wonder if there is some way to access this data on the device through the GUI for debugging (e.g., iTunesFilesharing with `UIFileSharingEnabled`, downloading the Container).